# Pode-se usar ênclise na frase: "há que se opor a ..."

Tags: gramática, sintaxe, pronomes

Frases com a estrutura "Há que se opor a alguma coisa" admitem ênclise? Ficaria "Há que opor-se a..."?

Comment: Bom, a resposta provavelmente é sim. A frase é que não soa a algo que alguém diria. Se estás a usar _haver que_ no sentido de _é preciso_ (e não no sentido de _não há que fazer_), então não entendo bem que lá faz o _se_. É suposto ser impessoal? Qual é a frase completa e o contexto?

Answer (score -1):

Não se usa ênclise depois de pronome relativo. A próclise é obrigatória nesse caso.

Referência: [Quando Usar a Ênclise](https://www.todamateria.com.br/quando-usar-a-enclise/).